# trying to make query with registers with comma separated

Tags: plsql

I have a table with these structure:

```
Field A     FieldB                  FieldC
material    clay,rush
material    air
metal       iron
metal       gold,silver,aluminium
```

What I need to do is fill in the C field. For this I have to make a query like:

```
select xxxxx from yyyyy where jjjjj in (material, clay, rush) 
select xxxxx from yyyyy where jjjjj in (material, air) 
select xxxxx from yyyyy where jjjjj in (metal, iron) 
select xxxxx from yyyyy where jjjjj in (metal, gold, silver, aluminum)
```

yyyy is another table.

Is possible to make these with pl/sql Oracle? I've been trying but I'm not capable, it seems a bit confusing. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Your table is not normalized properly, it does not follow [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) rules. The best you can do is to normalize your schema and don't store multiple values in a single column. If you don't do it, then a pain begins - you must parse this column into individual values in almost all queries.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fo you

```
DECLARE 
l_query VARCHAR(500);  
BEGIN
    FOR i in (SELECT FiledA, FiledB, FiledA||','||FiledB  AS  FiledC FROM test)
    LOOP
        l_query :=  'SELECT xxxxx FROM yyyyy WHERE jjjjj IN ';
        l_query := l_query||'('||i.FiledC||')';
        UPDATE  test
           SET FiledC = l_query
        WHERE FiledA = i.FiledA
          AND FiledB = i.FiledB;
        l_query := NULL;  
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```